# Number Theory Optimization Required

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

Given an integer n find smallest integer x such that φ(x) = n.

**(10^5 < n < 10^8)**

I know that lower bound for searching is **n+1** and the upper bound is

**n/((pow(e,0.577)*log(log(n))) + (3.0/(log(log(n)))))**

Can you please provide any other method for doing the same .

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a question about _Mathematica_ (a software) or Mathematics? If it's the latter, you should ask at [math.se]. if not, please show your (inefficient) code so far and where you're getting stuck. If it's neither and is a general programming question, you should ask at [so].

Comment: @rm-rf Code updated. Kindly see.

Comment: I think its the wrong site for my question. Isnt it ?

Comment: Yes. Wrong site. Mathematics is what you want.

Comment: Yes, this should be asked on [so]. I'll migrate this question to SO. Please create an account there to claim ownership of the migrated question

Comment: This answer belongs elsewhere, but please use `exp(x)` rather than `pow(e, x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was migrated to stackexchange Mathematica. Please see the Mathematica implementation invphi.nb by Maxim Rytin, available at http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/696/ . This code easily handles integers n in your range.

See also Chapter 3 in A Course in Computational Number Theory by Bressoud and Wagon.